# C++ return reference of object

Tags: c++

```
    MyClass& getMyClass() {return m_class}

private:

    myClass* m_class;
```

This gives me error msg:
 error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'myClass&' 
from expression of type 'myClass*'

What should I change to make it work? I want to return refenrence of this object. So I dont want to change getMyClass function prototype.

Comment: Pointers and references are different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to

```
return *m_class;
```

Make sure `m_class` is a valid pointer (e.g. not `NULL` or freed)!

Comment: @SteveTownsend picky picky :D

Comment: By valid pointer I mean one that points to memory that has been allocated and not freed - i.e. you need to be able to reference-ify m_class. So caution is needed when writing code like this - you should convince yourself that it is safe.

Comment: @JacobParker I think he's taking issue with "`NULL` or an invalid pointer" as if those are exclusive

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass &getMyClass() { return *m_class; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because pointers are not references, and you are returning a pointer, whereas should return a reference. In order to turn a pointer into a reference (in this case), you must de-reference a pointer, for example:

```
MyClass& getMyClass() {return *m_class}
```